# Why am I getting a string/hash comparison failure?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, httprequest

I've written a function that makes an HTTP GET request (truncated and simplified).

```
# get_request.rb
require "http"

def get_request
  HTTP.get("<https://github.com>")
end
```

I've written a test for the request.

```
require "request"

RSpec.describe "#get_request" do
  it "makes a successful GET request" do
    # GIVEN
    http_response = double("http", body: "Hello world!")

    # WHEN
    response = get_request

    # THEN
    expect(HTTP).to receive(:get).with("<https://github.com>").and_return(http_response)
    expect(response.body).to eq("Hello world!")
  end
end
```

However, the test fails with a comparison failure.

```
$ bundle exec rspec
F

Failures:

  1) #get_request makes a successful GET request
     Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to eq("Hello world!")

       expected: "Hello world!"
            got: #<HTTP::Response::Body:3fe63e519550 @streaming=false>

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -"Hello world!"
       +#<HTTP::Response::Body:3fe63e519550 @streaming=false>

     # ./spec/request_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.32713 seconds (files took 0.25261 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/request_spec.rb:4 # #get_request makes a successful GET request
```

Why does `response.body` equal the `<HTTP::Response::Body:3fe63e519550 @streaming=false>` hash and not the `"Hello world!"` string like I expected? How do I get the test to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have the exceptions at the bottom of your test, you have to use the spy pattern. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/spies

```rb
RSpec.describe "#get_request" do
  it "performs the request successfully" do
        http_response = double("http", body: "Hello world!")
        allow(HTTP).to receive(:get).and_return(http_response)

        response = get_request

        expect(HTTP).to have_received(:get).with("https://www.github.com")
        expect(response).to eq(http_response)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The test double needs to be in place before the function is called.¹ To get the test to pass, move the first expectation above the `get_request` method.

**For example:**

```
require "request"

RSpec.describe "#get_request" do
  it "makes a successful GET request" do
    # GIVEN
    http_response = double("http", body: "Hello world!")
    expect(HTTP).to receive(:get).with("<https://github.com>").and_return(http_response)

    # WHEN
    response = get_request

    # THEN
    expect(response.body).to eq("Hello world!")
  end
end
```

---

¹Thanks to [Jeremy Weathers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8794/jeremy-weathers) for helping answer the "why" part of the question.

Comment: Ryan, you are combining both the test double with the expectation, and the test double needs to be in place before the action part of your example. You should probably keep those de-tangled:
`allow(HTTP).to receive(:get).with("<https://github.com>").and_return(http_response)` in the GIVEN section and `expect(HTTP).to have_received(:get).with("<https://github.com>")` in the THEN section.

Comment: @JeremyWeathers "the test double needs to be in place before the action" is the key. Thanks for that answer!